# How i open Instagram in New Post mode?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-applications, instagram, instagram-api

With all respects, i'm not familiar to Instagram API.
But i want to open instagram in new post mode as i said.
For example: i think know Instagram downloaders.[image: Insta Downloader]

like instadownload.
how they open Instagram in new post mode?
I want to know it for Web Application and Android Application.
So i want to create a page with OpenDialog, Which choose a picture and then redirect to Instagram and land in New Post Mode.
Would you please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From instagram [docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/):

```
String type = "image/*";
String filename = "/myPhoto.jpg";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;

createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath);

private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String mediaPath){

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

Comment: @shmakova - It opens chooser from Instagram which asks for 'Instagram' and 'Story'
When I select Story then nothing happens

Comment: @AminAmiriDarban is this sending you to new post mode or first it prompts chooser for Story or Instagram??

Comment: @AkashDubey better to ask. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Not yet,
Even I cant find support for that from facebook too